# How to replace a token in a variable gotten form database with any given text?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a database where word documents are stored in longblob fields. I want to replace tokens like `[ID]` with some text. Haw can I add this functionality to the following code?

```
public function template_get()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_data($this->input->get());
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("id","id","required|integer");
        $data=array();
        if($this->form_validation->run()==False)
        {
            $data['status']=false;

            $data['error']=validation_errors();

        }
        else
        {
            $doc=$this->DocumentTemplateModel->get_single_document($this->input->get('id'));
            $file=$doc[0]["documento"];

            force_download($doc[0]['Nombre'],$file);
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your `force_download` function, but since documents are stored in longblob fields in database, I suppose, `force_download` just creates necessary headers to send the document that is wholly contained in `$file` variable.

Thus we should only replace token with necessary text inside `$file`.

```
// You may pass the token and the text to replace it
public function template_get($token, $text_to_replace_token)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_data($this->input->get());
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("id", "id", "required|integer");
    $data = array();
    if($this->form_validation->run() === false)
    {
        $data['status']=false;

        $data['error']=validation_errors();

        // Moved here because $data should only be echoed if form validation failed
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else
    {
        $doc = $this->DocumentTemplateModel->get_single_document($this->input->get('id'));
        $file = $doc[0]["documento"];

        // Replacing token with the given text
        $file = str_replace($token, $text_to_replace_token);

        force_download($doc[0]['Nombre'], $file);
    }

}
```

Comment: str_replace turn the result content to garbage because the this is .Doc(MsWord) file format